# VLAN configuration in linux not showing tags in tcpdump

Tags: linux, vlan, bonding

i  bonded 2 NIC and specified VLAN tag of 11

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0.11

```
DEVICE=bond0.11
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
STP=no
HOTPLUG=no
```

also

```
ifconfig bond0.11 192.168.211.6 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then

```
tcpdump -i bond0.11 -n -e
```

does not show any VLAN tags

even if there is any issue with physical interface or switch why dont i see tagged traffic in tcpdump when it enters interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct behaviour: the interface `bond0.11`is a VLAN-aware interface, so the only traffic that you should see on it is traffic for the VLAN of which it is a member (11), after those frames have been selected and the VLAN tags removed.

If you dump `bond0` you should see *all* the traffic that hits that physical interface, with tags intact.

Comment: hey thanks,you are right,also can you tell me is it normal to see other traffic on bond0 that is taffic that are not part of that VLAN,i can see traffic of eth2 in tcpdump of eth1

Comment: I have no idea, because you haven't told me how `eth1` and `eth2` are addressed and connected.  Are they the interfaces bonded to form `bond0`?  If so, it's completely normal; otherwise it might be normal, or it might be weird.  You might be better advised to open a new question about this - including a diagram, and all details of the various interfaces.